# Second FOR loop not entered in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I encountered strange behaviour in PL/pgSQL for PostgreSQL. I am making a function that has two separate FOR loops. The first one runs perfectly but the second seems to be forgotten. This is how the code looks roughly:

```
Declare r RECORD;

BEGIN
 FOR r in (select something from a)
 LOOP
  DO SOMETHING;
 END LOOP;
 r:=NULL;
 FOR r in (select something from b)
 LOOP
  DO SOMETHING;
 END LOOP;
END;
```

When put in separate functions both FOR loops work well. I also tried to use 2 separate record variables but that didn't work either.

I can't understand why the second loop is ignored.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably you need to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow/help/mcve). Regrettably, this is more difficult for database related questions because you should include code for creating and populating data tables. And in this case, you should print code that creates the function.

Comment: Please provide a *complete* function definition including the function header. PL/pgSQL functions don't make much sense without. Actual code, pseudo-code is not good for this case. ("PL/SQL" is the Oracle procedural language btw.)